# Android custom lint does not work automaticly

Tags: android, android-studio, lint

I created a custom lint rule as a module for my project, the Detector is working correctly and has tests that validate that is working, I then added this lint module as a dependency of a common module that all other modules depend `lintPublish project(':lint')`

Here is my custom rule but it only shows after runing the `./gradlew lint` command and onlt if the lint detects that a rule is not respected, because if every thing is ok the rule does not show here, so when we change the code and an error was supposed to happen it does not automatically detects it[image]

Closing Android studio losses this configurations and I'm required to run the lint task again, any ideas of what I'm doing wrong? Shouldn't this be automatically added to the lint rules of the project?

- Android Studio 4.0-beta02
- Gradlew 4.0.0-beta02
- Gradle 6.1.1
- lint 27.1.0-alpha02